# Move a file to a directory in the filesystem with emacs lisp

Tags: files, directories

What is the function to move files? I want to emulate the following shell command:

```
mv file dir
```

As described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Files.html#Changing-Files), the closest is `rename-file`, but this would be emulating this:

```
mv file newfile
```

Answer (score 5):

That function can actually move files to directories, but its documentation was not in accord with its features. If the destination ends in a <kbd>/</kbd>, then the file is moved. e.g.

`(rename-file "foo" "bar/")`

will move foo into the directory bar.

Comment: is a slash portable? How to build a dirname from a string in a portable way?

Comment: `(file-name-as-directory "bar")` is the portable way to do that.

Comment: OP: Please consider accepting this answer. I believe it's what you're looking for.